# How to find the list of individual resources that have access to a given SPN?

Tags: azure, graph, rbac

When I use az login using service principal

e.g `az login --service-principal -u “12121” -p “1212” --tenant “12121”`

It will show the all the list of subscriptions which it has access like

```
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "123",
    "id": "215645",
    "isDefault": true,
    "managedByTenants": [],
    "name": "Sub1",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "123",
    "user": {
      "name": "123456",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  },
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "123",
    "id": "rr",
    "isDefault": false,
    "managedByTenants": [
      {
        "tenantId": "123"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Sub2",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "123",
    "user": {
      "name": "123456",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  },
...
...
]
```

Among the list for some sub the SPN have direct reader access(RBAC) to the subscription. But for the other sub (lets say `sub2`) the access is not directly given to the subscription level, instead the access has been given to resource(s) level.

**Question**: How to get all the list of resources within `sub2` that have access provided to the service principal ?in other words, I have to find(list) what kind of access the service principal assigned to any/all the resources within `sub2`.

I know azure cli doing this behind the scene to retrieve this information.That why it can show all the list of subscription after the successful login. But i don't know what that is

Is there any cli command or graph API to retrieve that information ?

*P.S:I don't know the scope or resource where the SPN is assigned too*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list the role assignments for a specific user, you can use the [az role assignment list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-cli?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#list-role-assignments-for-a-user) command.

```
az role assignment list --assignee {assignee}
```

**Note:** To view role assignments for the current subscription and below, add the `--all` parameter:

```
az role assignment list --assignee {assignee} --all
```

If you are already logged in with the service principal, you can omit the `--assignee` parameter

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately this only gives the subscription level assignment by default. My requirement is more like i dont know where the spn had the access . It many be assigned on any scopes(resources) which i dont in advance. If i know the scope i can directly pass the scope as the parameter, but in my case its not

Comment: Hm, pleaes check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-cli

Comment: got it , All i have to include is `--all` at the last, which will search through every resources inside the subscription and give the result . Could you please update your answer with this. Happy to accept that :)

Comment: thanks for the feeback. I am happy that you got your desired output and edited my answer.